# sending file to upload script using ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an **by the user dropped file to the php upload** script using ajax. I don't know why it doesn't work, **nothing happens** if I drop an image.

(**Why's no one answering?**)

So this is the **html** part:

```
<div id="dropzone" class="dropzone" 
     ondragenter="return false;"
     ondragover="return false"
     ondrop="drop(event)">
    Drop here!
</div>
```

And this is the **js function**:

```
// drag n' drop
function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var datei = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    if(datei && datei.type.match("image/*")) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var uploadfile = event.target.result;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'imgupload.php');

            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append('upload', uploadfile);
            xhr.send(formdata);

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(datei);
    }
}
```

**So what am I doing wrong? What needs to be changed?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This Q is currently 2 hours old - we're all sitting here, starring at our screens and just waiting for that one question from you ....

Comment: Don't know what should happen, see http://jsfiddle.net/ppax2auu/1/ but it seems that `dropzone` is not a droppable actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite easy. I should **not** have used **FileReader()**.

This is working:

```
// drag n' drop
function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var datei = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    if(datei && datei.type.match("image/*")) {

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('upload', datei);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'imgupload.php');
        xhr.send(formdata);

    }
}
```